# jQuery.fn.scroll() event shorthand is deprecated

Tags: jquery, jquery-migrate

I'm upgrading jQuery in my project to a recent version 3.4.1. I set up `jquery-migrate` and look in the browser console to see things I should modify. Among others it reads `jQuery.fn.scroll() event shorthand is deprecated`.

My code is simple: `divBody.scroll();`.

The [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/)  says: `To trigger the event manually, apply .scroll() without an argument:`. I firmly believe this is what I'm doing. Why does migrate still complain?

Comment: For details see [future release discussion](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3214)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears that the documentation has not been updated to reflect the deprecation. See the [warning messages for the jQuery Migrate Plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md#jqmigrate-jqueryfnclick-event-shorthand-is-deprecated) (specifically the event shorthand deprecations).

Per the solution provided there, the following code should work, removing the deprecation warning:

```
divBody.trigger("scroll");
```